# jQuery DataTables not having all post values when using datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery Datatables, and am trying to combine it with a datetime picker (https://miamarti.github.io/Material-DateTimePicker/).

My filters at the top are custom coded, but it does not appear to be causing the problem.

The filters are constructed like this, when not using the datetime picker (dates hardcoded for explanation):

`PHP`

```
$filters['Staged Date'] = [
    'column' => 16,
    'id' => 'stage_date',
    'name' => 'stage_date',
    'options' => [
        '2023-07-01 00:00:00' => '2023-07-01 00:00:00',
        '2023-07-02 00:00:00' => '2023-07-02 00:00:00',
        '2023-07-03 00:00:00' => '2023-07-03 00:00:00'
    ]
];
```

However, when using the datepicker, the code changes to this:

`PHP`

```
$filters['Staged Date'] = [
    'column' => 16,
    'class' => 'timepickerfield',
    'text_field' => true,
    'id' => 'stage_date',
    'name' => 'stage_date',
    'options' => []
];
```

`Javascript/jQuery`

```
    $('#stage_date').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
        format : 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        switchOnClick : true,
        weekStart : 0
    }).on('close', function(e) {
        $('#stage_date').val($(this).val() + ':00').trigger('change');
        var table = $('#dt-transaction-list').DataTable();
        table.ajax.reload();
    });
```

I know the 'close' event is firing, because the datetime picker field is updated with the ':00' at the end of the date after selection. I can also see that the table is reloading. There are no errors in my console either.

Without the datetime picker the POST data looks like this (shortened with relevant data only):

```
Array
(
    [columns] => Array
        (
            ...
            [16] => Array
                (
                    [data] => stage_date
                    [name] => stage_date
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 2023-07-03 00:00:00
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )
            ...
        )
)
```

But with the datetime picker, the value index of `columns > 16 > search > value` is blank.

Any ideas, please? I am going more grey by the minute.